# How to convert varchar2 input parameter to timestamp in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

We are using a proprietary product to develop our application. This product is capable of connecting to Oracle DB and executes SQL queries and stored procedures.
However, today we found a weird issue that this product is not able to execute a stored procedure if there is a timestamp input parameter in stored procedure.

We are now trying to change 'p_timestamp' input parameter from timestamp to varchar2. So, application will send timestamp value as a string and then before/while executing insert statement inside stored procedure we want to convert this varchar2 value into timestamp. Also, this timestamp should be stored in UTC time zone.

How to convert the 'p_timestamp' varchar2 input parameter into timestamp?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE MYAPPROVALS_AUDIT (
    ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    MESSAGE_TYPE VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
    COMPONENT_NAME VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
    USERNAME VARCHAR2(32 CHAR),
    TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    REQUEST_NUMBER VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
    MODULE_NAME VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
    PROCESS_NAME VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
    VERSION VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
    TASK VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
    ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
    ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
    MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYAPPROVALS_AUDIT_INSERT_RECORD(
       p_message_Type IN myapprovals_audit.message_type%TYPE,
       p_component_Name IN myapprovals_audit.component_name%TYPE,
       p_username IN myapprovals_audit.USERNAME%TYPE,
       p_timestamp IN varchar2,
       p_request_Number IN myapprovals_audit.request_number%TYPE,
       p_module_Name IN myapprovals_audit.module_name%TYPE,
       p_process_Name IN myapprovals_audit.process_name%TYPE,
       p_version IN myapprovals_audit.version%TYPE,
       p_task IN myapprovals_audit.task%TYPE,
       p_error_Code IN myapprovals_audit.error_code%TYPE,
       p_error_Message IN myapprovals_audit.error_message%TYPE,
       p_message IN myapprovals_audit.message%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO MYAPPROVALS_AUDIT ("MESSAGE_TYPE", "COMPONENT_NAME", "USERNAME", "TIMESTAMP", "REQUEST_NUMBER", "MODULE_NAME", "PROCESS_NAME", "VERSION", "TASK", "ERROR_CODE", "ERROR_MESSAGE", "MESSAGE") 
  VALUES (p_message_Type, p_component_Name, p_username, TO_TIMESTAMP(trunc(p_timestamp)) at time zone 'UTC', p_request_Number, p_module_Name, p_process_name, p_version, p_task, p_error_Code, p_error_Message, p_message);

  COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Comment: What do your varchar timestamps look like? And can you show the error you are getting if you run this procedure now?

Comment: It would really be helpful to include the error you got passing a timestamp, and what the issue/error is with what you have now. The `TO_TIMESTAMP(trunc(p_timestamp)) at time zone 'UTC'` looks suspicious; was it doing that before, or has that expression been modified?

Comment: "TIMESTAMP" is a reserved word. How did you manage to get that as a column name? You have to jump through hopes in order to use reserved words as object names, and that alone should be a huge red flag against doing so.

Comment: @EdStevens `TIMESTAMP` is not reserved like `DATE` is. There is no problem using it as an identifier (other than being slightly confusing [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6db9df7008edfd1ac93d6ee71278dea2)).

Comment: @MT0 - Interesting.  Especially since it is used to specify a data type.  Just the same, I'd avoid using anything that even _looks_ like a reserved word.  That's one reason I often suggest that the baseline for column names be that they are in the format 'adjective_noun' (or 'noun_adjective' if the locally used language structures the grammar that way).   Avoids any confusion, and makes the names more meaningful and self-documenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input is in ISO8601 format with fractional seconds and a time zone then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYAPPROVALS_AUDIT_INSERT_RECORD(
  p_message_Type   IN myapprovals_audit.message_type%TYPE,
  p_component_Name IN myapprovals_audit.component_name%TYPE,
  p_username       IN myapprovals_audit.USERNAME%TYPE,
  p_timestamp      IN varchar2,
  p_request_Number IN myapprovals_audit.request_number%TYPE,
  p_module_Name    IN myapprovals_audit.module_name%TYPE,
  p_process_Name   IN myapprovals_audit.process_name%TYPE,
  p_version        IN myapprovals_audit.version%TYPE,
  p_task           IN myapprovals_audit.task%TYPE,
  p_error_Code     IN myapprovals_audit.error_code%TYPE,
  p_error_Message  IN myapprovals_audit.error_message%TYPE,
  p_message        IN myapprovals_audit.message%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MYAPPROVALS_AUDIT (
    MESSAGE_TYPE,       -- You do not need to quote identifiers.
    COMPONENT_NAME,
    USERNAME,
    TIMESTAMP,
    REQUEST_NUMBER,
    MODULE_NAME,
    PROCESS_NAME,
    VERSION,
    TASK,
    ERROR_CODE,
    ERROR_MESSAGE,
    MESSAGE
  ) VALUES (
    p_message_Type,
    p_component_Name,
    p_username,
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(                       -- Assuming TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
      p_timestamp,
      'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM' -- Your timestamp format model
    ) at time zone 'UTC',
    p_request_Number,
    p_module_Name,
    p_process_name,
    p_version,
    p_task,
    p_error_Code,
    p_error_Message,
    p_message
  );

  -- Do not COMMIT in the procedure.
  -- COMMIT when you finalise the transaction that way you can chain multiple
  -- procedures together and if one fails ROLLBACK the entire transaction.
END;
/
```

If it is in a different format then change the format model to suit your data.

Comment: @MTO Input will be like '2022-04-01T17:32:22.223Z'. Also, we are still in UAT phase and PROD is still good 2 months away. I will try this solution and confirm the outcome. Thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Input will be like '2022-04-01T17:32:22.223Z'

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you can use [TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ.html), i.e. instead of

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(trunc(p_timestamp)) at time zone 'UTC'
```

you can do

```
TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ(p_timestamp)
```

That will give you a timestamp with time zone, as UTC; if you want a plain timestamp you can cast it, implicitly during your insert, or explicitly:

```
CAST(TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ(p_timestamp) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

If the passed string is always exactly that format and always UTC, with the Z indicator, and you want to end up with a plain timestamp, you could also do:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(p_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"')
```

Quick [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bed2e5f17bfb1de726665f29663d56d8) showing all three, with your example string value.

---

It would probably still be better to investigate why the product is having a problem with timestamps, so you can make it pass the correct data type and avoid the conversion.

Comment: I already tried the solution suggested by @MTO and it worked fine. Thank you for suggesting alternate way to implement this requirement. Vender will take their own sweet time even to accept the bug. So, we are going with this workaround for now.